# Modifying an Aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get my surgeries to calculate at different rates and I am struggling with it. For example, patient 58903 has 4 total surgeries as shown below. However, I would like the first surgery to calculate at 100% of the PPO SURG rate (so $4232), the second one at 50%, and all remaining surgeries at 25% of the main PPO SURG rate. My current code returns $16,929 for patient 5903 which is just $4232*4. My desired output for the SURG Total below is $8,464 (4232+2116+1058+1058).

My Current Code:

```
SELECT 

DISTINCT PATNO, 
SUM( PPOSURG) AS 'Surg Total',
SUM( PPONONSURG) AS 'Non Surg Total',
SUM( PPODRUG) AS 'Drug Total',
INSNME,
IIF( SUM( PPOSURG) IS NOT NULL,
SUM( PPOSURG) + SUM(CASE WHEN REV=278 THEN (AMT1)*0.446 END),
ISNULL(SUM( PPODRUG),0)+ISNULL( SUM( PPONONSURG),0)) AS 'Claim Total'

FROM

[OPGRACE$] AS GR --Main Table

LEFT JOIN [BCSURGOP$] AS SRG ON GR.CPTCDA=SRG.[CPTCODESURG] --SURG joined on cpt
LEFT JOIN [BCBSDRUG$] AS DRUG ON GR.CPTCDA=DRUG.[CPT CODE] --DRUG Schedules joined on cpt
LEFT JOIN [BCBSNONSURGOP$] AS NSRG ON GR.CPTCDA=NSRG.[CPT CODE] --Non-SURG joined on cpt

WHERE QTY>0 AND PATNO>0 

GROUP BY PATNO,INSNME
ORDER BY PATNO ASC
```

I tried doing something like this but you can't have an aggregate in a SUM

```
SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(CPTCODESURG)=1 THEN PPOSURG ELSE PPOSURG*0.5 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN REV=278 THEN (AMT1)*0.446 END),
```

Here is my output for just patient 58903

| SURG Total | Non Surg Total | Drug Total | CLAIM Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16929.472 | 3103 | 179 | 22598.84 |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

Here is a blurb of my joined table showing how patient 58903 shows up:

| PName | Rev | CPT | PPOSURG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58903 | 360 | 29882 | 4232.368 |
| 58903 | 360 | 29882 | 4232.368 |
| 58903 | 360 | 29882 | 4232.368 |
| 58903 | 360 | 29882 | 4232.368 |

Would a PARTITION be the way to go here? A subquery? Can I somehow use a case statement? I don't expect anyone to write my code but literally any ideas would be extremely helpful, I have been really stuck on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just need a row number partitioned by the patient and then a `CASE` *expression* to convert that into a multiplier. I've added an `id` column to the sample data to allow for an `order by` (which you need for a row number).

```
declare @Test table (id int identity(1,1), PName int, Rev int, CPT int, PPOSURG money);

insert into @Test (PName, Rev, CPT, PPOSURG)
values
(58903, 360, 29882, 4232.368),
(58903, 360, 29882, 4232.368),
(58903, 360, 29882, 4232.368),
(58903, 360, 29882, 4232.368);

with cte as (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by PName order by id) rn
    from @Test
)
select PName, Rev, CPT
    , cast(sum(PPOSURG * case rn when 1 then 1.00 when 2 then 0.50 else 0.25 end) as decimal(9,2)) Total
from cte
group by PName, Rev, CPT;
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly the logic I need! That code is more advanced than what I am able to do but I'll start Googling to understand it better. Thank you!